# How to get the android 12 clock's app BottomNavigationView?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-12, material-you

I want to get the new `BottomNavigationView` in android studio.

Here is a new navigation photo.

[image: Screenshot]

This is the new `BottomNavigationView` design in the last update in clock apps in android.

I tried to get this `BottomNavigationView` but I couldn't find it.

Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This BottomNavigationView is just a normal BottomNavigationView from the Material Library. However,  you need to update your Material Design dependencies to the latest version (`1.5.0-beta01` at the time of writing) and set your theme to `Theme.Material3.` in styles.xml or themes.xml.